# Error Function or interface marked as restricted, or the function uses an Automation type not supported in Visual Basic in VB6

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, vb6

I have an array in C# which has to be initialized in VB. While initializing I am getting an error "Function or interface marked as restricted, or the function uses an Automation type not supported in Visual Basic."

C#.Net Code :

```
public class InventoryMasterSearchSettings
{

   public string[] PrintLabelsIDetail { get; set; }

}
```

VB.Net Code:

```
Public Property PrintLabelsIDetail() As String()                
    Get
        PrintLabelsIDetail = mInventoryMasterSearchSettings.PrintLabelsIDetail
    End Get
    Set(value As String())
        mInventoryMasterSearchSettings.PrintLabelsIDetail = value
    End Set
End Property
```

VB6

```
Public Sub ShowPrintLabels(invmast() As String, bShowAvailableInventoryOnlyPar As Boolean, Optional fCalledFromScreen As Form, Optional sVendorIDPar As String, Optional sUPCCodePar As String, Optional sInventoryDescriptionPar As String)
    Dim oInventoryMasterSearchSettings As New Shared_Interop.InventoryMasterSearchSettings
    oInventoryMasterSearchSettings.PrintLabelsIDetail = invmast           'error on PrintLabelsIDetail
End Sub
```

Comment: I think you have an old Active X class that is not registered.  Microsoft obsoleted Active X around 2004.  The methods can still be used if they are added to the machine registry.  It looks like you are trying to upgrade a very old VB6 project to VB.Net and getting this error.

Comment: How Can I solve this now?

Comment: You would have to find the dll (library) that contained the Shared_Interop and then register the library.

Comment: Is `Shared_Interop` the namespace in C#?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the type of mInventoryMasterSearchSettings.PrintLabelsIDetail is a standard array? (not a collection, or a arraylist type)

You could try two things.

First - use a compiler directive to force the array as a COM "safe" array.

```
Public Property PrintLabelsIDetail() As  <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SafeArray)> String()                
    Get
        PrintLabelsIDetail = mInventoryMasterSearchSettings.PrintLabelsIDetail
    End Get
    Set(value As String())
        mInventoryMasterSearchSettings.PrintLabelsIDetail = value
    End Set
End Property
```

So, above may well help marshal the array() of strings to somthing more compatiable with the COM side from a consuming point of view.

The other idea? You could do  a cast of the type before you return it.

So, say like this:

```
Public Property PrintLabelsIDetail() As <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SafeArray)> String()

    Get
        PrintLabelsIDetail = DirectCast(mInventoryMasterSearchSettings.PrintLabelsIDetail, String())
    End Get
    Set(value As String())
        mInventoryMasterSearchSettings.PrintLabelsIDetail = value
    End Set
End Property
```

Also, if the array of string() type is not initialized, then you might want to ensure that has occurred before you return that array.

As a general rule, you CAN pass a array from the COM side to .net, but you USEALLY MUST send  that array as byref and NOT byval.

However, you are going the the other way. .net --> COM side. A plane jane array of string type usually can go to COM side, and even so without the above marshalas compiler directive.

I would try one or the other idea, or in fact as my 2nd example does, try adding both a marshal compiler directive, and a cast.

My spider sense suggests that the data type of PrintLabelsIDetail is a collection, iList, or arrarylist when it need to be a array() of string type. So, check the data type of PrintLabelsIDetail - I not tested but I don't think COM will even like a arrayList in place of Array. And you would do well to initialize the array before sending it across the COM bridge

## Edit

I was having a coffee - the directcast might get you a COM/ActiveX compatible array, but I "think" it may well break the connection. (the VB6 side would be modifying a copy - it may well not persist in the COM object members) - so try the compiler directive without the directcast suggestion

Comment: The compiler directive should work. You certainly need a Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices (vb.net). I can't imagine you achieved "any" success without the inter-op services name space having been imported.  So, for that compiler directive to work, you need the Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices imported.